# How to pull <p> tags from an external html page and rotate between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built up a website without any server side scripting/language, using only HTML/JavaScript/jQuery.

In my website, there's a plain stream.html page that I have kept (with no css, formatting etc.)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="textParagraphs">
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<p>Para 3</p>
<p>Para 4</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In all other html pages that I have (with divs/formatting/css etc.), I intend to keep a section in the header that picks ups the top three `<p>` sections from the page, and displays them with by a rotation effect.
For eg: After is has the three paragraphs, it should display Para1 -> fade out -> Para2 -> Fade out -> Para3

How do I go about pulling the `<p>` sections from another page and displaying them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can get the content of that html page using `jQuery.get()` function.
Then in the result you should search for `<p>` tags using `jQuery(result).find("p")`.
Now that you have arrays of the `p` tags you can rotate between using this simple `carousel` script:

```
var carousel = {
    _defaultParameters: {
        container: null,
        paragraphs: [],
        timeout: 3000,
        nextItemIndex: 0
    },

    rotate: function(param){
        var param = $.extend(true, {}, this._defaultParameters, param);

        if(param.paragraphs.length == 0) return;
        if(param.nextItemIndex > param.paragraphs.length - 1){
            param.nextItemIndex = 0;
        }

        param.container.empty().append(param.paragraphs[param.nextItemIndex]);

        param.nextItemIndex++;
        setTimeout(function(){ carousel.rotate(param); }, param.timeout);
     }
}

$(function(){

    jQuery.get('data_source.html', function(result) { // replace data_source.html with your external html file url
        var paragraphs = jQuery(result).find("p");

        carousel.rotate({
            container: $("#rotatorContainerID"), //replace this with your container
            paragraphs: paragraphs
        });
    });

});
```

Replace `'data_source.html'` with address of your external html file that contains that `<p>` tags. Also change the `container: $("#rotatorContainerID")` to the `id` of your element that will host the `<p>` tags and rotation will be ocucred in it.

To demo the `carousel` functionality you can check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5AgcE/4/

Comment: nice, I didn't know you can wrap arbitrary strings in query like that, excellent!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend storing these paragraphs as JSON instead.

Then you can request them from each page using jquery `$.getJSON()` instead of having to parse the HTML document.  If you want to maintain the stream.html file, you can have that fetch the JSON and print all of them instead of just handling the top three.

Check out the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Once you have the list of (3) items you can set up a carousel (google for `carousel javascript`).  There are tons of scripts or jQuery plugins to do this, find one that you like!

Answer (score -2):

This is the easiest way:

```
var allPs = $('p');

var p1 = $(allPs[0]).html();

var p2 = $(allPs[1]).html();

var p3 = $(allPs[2]).html();
```

You can also add some test like:

```
if(allPs.length >= 3) {

}
```

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean from a different page.  Also, I would be as selective as possible `$('#textParagraphs > p')`